# Adding "Page write count" functionality to a SIGSEGV signal handler

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, signals

First, I used the mprotect function to make a memory area non-writable.

```
if (mprotect(mem_vadrs, offset, PROT_READ) == 0)
{
    return 1;
}
else
{
    perror("mprotect failed\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Then I will execute the related write commands in this memory area and trigger a segment error.
Inside the signal handler function, I restore the region to writeable and record the address(logical address) of the region.After this step, what else do I need to do inside my signal processing function?As a learner, I don't know much about what the Linux kernel does when dealing with SIGSEGV signal.This is the code of SIGSEGV signal handler.

```
printf("Got SIGSEGV at address: %p\n",(long) si->si_addr);
unsigned long pagenum = (unsigned long)si->si_addr / 4096;
unsigned long pageaddr = pagenum * 4096;//mprotect requires that the parameter be the page starting address
unsigned long phyaddr = 0x0;//Not yet
mprotect(pageaddr, 4096, PROT_WRITE);
printf("pageaddr:%p\n",pageaddr);
```

As the code shown.In the signal handler function, I made the page that had been set to non-writable writable again, so that every page write can be captured by me and the program can run normally.
My goal is to count the number of physical pages written to a specific memory area in a process, and here I only get the logical page address.I know I can read the file "pagemap" to get the page mapping, but it doesn't seem thread-safe to write these operations into signal handlers, which I do, and which triggers a lot of errors.
Do you have any Suggestions?

Comment: `printf("Got SIGSEGV at address: %p\n",(long) si->si_addr);` and `printf("pageaddr:%p\n",pageaddr);` invokes *undefined behavior* for type mismatch. What is printed via `%p` should be casted to `void*`.

Comment: Unsigned long, to be precise.Thanks!

Comment: Regarding: `printf("Got SIGSEGV at address: %p\n",(long) si->si_addr);` and `printf("pageaddr:%p\n",pageaddr)`  There are a lot of functions that are 'unsafe' in signal handlers,  `printf()` is one of them.  See: `man 7 signals` and `man 7 signal-safety`

Comment: thanks for u and I know that so I'll delete it when I actually finish writing the program